# how to open template with button click

Tags: django

I want to open another template like "booking" in following example by clicking.

- projectforms

  - bookingform

    - urls
    - templates

      - index.html
  - projectforms

    - urls

**bookingform.urls**

```
urlpatterns = [
path('' , views.purchasing_view, name="purchasing"),
path('',views.add_model, name="booking"),
path('' , views.payment_view, name="payment"),
path('' , views.payment_view, name="payroll"),
]
```

**projectforms.urls**

```
from bookingform.views import add_model, 
purchasing_view,payment_view,payroll_view,index_view


urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('', index_view),
path('booking/',add_model),
path('purchasing/', purchasing_view),
path('payments/', payment_view),
path('payroll/', payroll_view),
]
```

How to call "booking" url with following button.

```
 <a class="btn">Booking</a>
```

Comment: You can't do this. You have four URLs all with the empty pattern. How is the server supposed to know which is which when you request that path? You need to give them all individual paths, then refer to that path in the `href` attribute of your link.

Comment: Okay, but I am sending the path from projectforms.urls

Comment: So why do you have two urls at all? How are they related? What is the point of bookingform.urls? Why don't the patterns in projectform.urls have names?

Comment: so you are saying i need to give paths in bookingform.urls and how it can be accessed with  projectform.urls. I am a beginner here. can you please recommend me how can i play with urls easily

Comment: I don't understand your question. You aren't using bookingform.urls, since it is not used anywhere. And all the paths in projectform.urls need to have names, like the ones in bookingforms currently do. Really, all this is very well covered in the tutorial, which you should read fully.

Comment: You need to go through official docs, your urlpatterns are wrong.

Comment: I have fixed my urlpatterns and now its working. Thanks all :)

Answer (score 0):

It was issue with urlpatterns.

**projectforms.urls**

```
urlpatterns = {
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('',include(('bookingform.urls','index'), namespace='index')),
}
```

**bookingform.urls**

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.index_view, name="index"),
url(r'booking', views.add_model, name="booking"),
url(r'purchasing', views.purchasing_view, name="purchasing"),
url(r'payments', views.payment_view, name="payments"),
url(r'payroll', views.payroll_view, name="payroll"),
]
```